# Replacing only the first occurrence of a word in a string

Tags: powershell

I am having some issues with regular expression mainly because I think the information I can find is not specifically for powershell and all the samples I have tried either error or don't work as intended. I am trying to replace the first occurrence of a word in a string with another word but not replace any other occurrences of that word. for an example take the string:

`My name is Bob, her name is Sara.`

I would like to replace the first occurrence of `name` with `baby` so the resulting string would be

`My baby is Bob, her name is Sara.`

I have been working in https://regex101.com/ to try to build and see what is selected as I go but as I said none of these have a powershell flavor of regex. In that I can just turn off the `global` flag and it seems to select the first occurrence but not in powershell. So I am really at a loss of where to begin all really have at this point is selecting all occurrences of the word `name`with:

```
$test = "My name is Bob, her name is Sara."
$test -replace 'name', 'baby'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could capture everything before and behind and replace it:

```
'My name is Bob, her name is Sara.' -replace '(.*?)name(.*)', '$1baby$2'
```

Comment: Wow that worked great. I think I was close to that I tried some examples like that with `$1` and `$2` but couldn't get it to work properly. Thanks for the help. I didn't fully understand how the examples work but this makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: Nice! Using the anchor `^` for the start of the string, the 2nd capture group could be omitted: `'My name is Bob, her name is Sara.' -replace '^(.*?)name', '$1baby'`. See [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/ojgKte/1)

Answer (score 47):

One way to replace *n* times:

```
$test = "My name is Bob, her name is Sara."
[regex]$pattern = "name"
$pattern.replace($test, "baby", 1) 

> My baby is Bob, her name is Sara
```

Comment: So the `1` Just says replace the first one you find ? A `2` would replace both then ? If you said `3` and only have 2 words of `name` would it error or only replace the first 2 ?

Comment: Yes, its the number of replacements to make.  If you pass a number greater then the actual frequency of the word it will just replace them all.

Comment: This is a much more intuitive way to do this, and works with variables much better.

Comment: The syntax with the square brackets is not intuitive for me. Could someone point me to the documentation.

Comment: @MauiMuc `[Type]` in front of a variable definition applies a _type constraint_. It restricts what kind of data can be assigned to the variable. If the value on the right-hand-side can be converted to the type, then the conversion is applied, in this case `String` to `Regex`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66996505/7571258) for details.