# What do you call these? [array][string][int]

Tags: .net, powershell, terminology

What are these called? When scripting in powershell I can use them to set or convert the data type of my variable, but what is the term for this? Is there an official doc for these?

Example:

```
$var = @("hello","world")
If ($var -is [array]) { write-host "$var is an array" }
```

Comment: They’re basically references to dotnet Types - e.g. ```[string].GetType().Name``` returns ```RuntimeType```.

Comment: Kind of a trick question since Powershell handles it for you in regards to what it becomes. No need to cast a data type to it, posh knows. Such as `$Var = 2` will be a data type of int. Same with `$Var = "string"`, will be a data type of `[string]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Don Cruickshank's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66995445/45375) provides one piece of the puzzle, but let me try give a comprehensive overview:

***By itself*, a `[<fullTypeNameOrTypeAccelerator>]` expression is a *type literal***, i.e. a reference to a *.NET type* in the form of a [`System.Reflection.TypeInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Reflection.TypeInfo) instance, which is rich source of *reflection* on the type it represents.

`<fullTypeNameOrTypeAccelerator>` can be the full name of a .NET type (e.g., [`[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex) - optionally with the `System.` prefix omitted (`[Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]`) or the name of a PowerShell [*type accelerator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Accelerators) (e.g, `[regex]`)

---

Type literals ***by themselves*** are used:

- Typically, to **access *static members*** (typically methods) via **`::`**, the [static member-access operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#static-member-operator-); e.g.:

  ```bash
  # Call the static 'Match' method of the [regex]
  # (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex) type.
  # -> '10'
  [regex]::Match('A10', '\d+').Value
  ```
- Less frequently, to **reflect on the given type** by calling the instance methods of the [`TypeInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Reflection.TypeInfo) instance that every type literal is; e.g.:

  ```bash
  # Get the names of all .NET interfaces that the [regex]
  # (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex) implements.
  # -> 'ISerializable'
  [regex].GetInterfaces().Name
  ```

---

Type literals are ***also* used in the following constructs**:

- **As [*casts*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#cast-operator--)**, to ***convert*** (coerce) the (RHS<sup>[1]</sup>) operand to the specified type or to **construct** an instance, if possible:

  ```bash
  # Convert a string to [datetime] (System.DateTime).
  # Equivalent to the following call:
  #    [datetime]::Parse('1970-01-01', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
  [datetime] '1970-01-01'

  # Construct a [regex] instance.
  # The same as the following constructor call:
  #     [regex]::new('\d+')
  $re = [regex] '\d+'
  ```

  - The examples show that PowerShell **casts are *much more flexible* than in C#**, for instance, and *instance construction* and *type conversions* frequently happen *implicitly* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63982452/45375) for more information. The same rules apply to all the other uses listed below.
- **As *type constraints***:

  - To *specify the type* of a [*parameter*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions#named-parameters) variable in a function or script:

    ```bash
    function foo { param([datetime] $d) $d.Year }; foo '1970-01-01'
    ```
  - To *lock in the type* of a *regular* [variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Variables) for all future assignments:<sup>[2]</sup>

    ```bash
    [datetime] $foo = '1970-01-01'
    # ...
    $foo = '2021-01-01' # the string is now implicitly forced to [datetime]
    ```
- As the **RHS of the `-is` and `-as` operators**, for [type tests and conditional conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Operators):

  - `-is` tests not only for the exact type, but also for *derived* types as well as *interface* implementations:

    ```bash
    # Exact type match (the `Get-Date` cmdlet outputs instances of [datetime])
    (Get-Date) -is [datetime]  # $true

    # Match via a *derived* type:
    # `Get-Item /` outputs an instance of type [System.IO.DirectoryInfo],
    # which derives from [System.IO.FileSystemInfo]
    (Get-Item /) -is [System.IO.FileSystemInfo] # $true

    # Match via an *interface* implementation:
    # Arrays implement the [System.Collections.IEnumerable] interface.
    1..3 -is [System.Collections.IEnumerable] # true
    ```
  - `-as` converts the LHS instance to an instance of the RHS type *if possible*, and returns `$null` otherwise:

    ```bash
    '42' -as [int] # 42

    'foo' -as [int] # $null
    ```
- ***[PowerShell v7.3+ only]*** As the ***type arguments* in *generic method calls***:

  - E.g, the following calls the [`Enumerable.OfType<TResult>(IEnumerable)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Linq.Enumerable.OfType) LINQ method with `[int]` as its type argument (thereby requesting that only enumerable elements that are of that type be returned):

    ```bash
    # -> 2, 4
    [System.Linq.Enumerable]::OfType[int](@('one', 2, 'three', 4))
    ```
  - See [about_Calling_Generic_Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calling_Generic_Methods).

---

<sup>[1] In the context of operators and mathematical equations, the initialisms LHS and RHS are commonly used, referring to the *left-hand side* and *right-hand side* operands, respectively.</sup>

<sup>[2] Technically, there is no real difference between a *parameter* and a *regular* variable: the type constraints functions the same way in both cases, but parameter variables, after having been bound (assigned to) automatically on *invocation*, aren't usually assigned to *again*.</sup>

Comment: Great answer, as usual! If I may, I wanna add a good article to understand a bit more on the subject https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/programmer-dictionary-class-vs-type-vs-object-e6d1f74d1e2e and of course the System Namespace from MS Docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system?view=net-5.0

Comment: What is RHS? So, *"under the hood"* for powershell cmdlets, do actual .Net types lie? Such as the ones you referenced for exact match like: `Get-Date` is actually just `[DateTime]`, but in Powershell syntax? Still just confused on when I get the data type back from piping a cmdlet to a `Get-Member`, is it just grabbing those objects that lie in those types, or is it the actual type itself? -pardon me if this doesn't make sense

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, re LHS and RHS: please see the footnote I've just added. I'm not sure I understand your other question: `Get-Date` is a _cmdlet_ that _outputs_ instances of `[datetime]`. You pipe _instances_ to `Get-Member`, which then tells you about their _type_.

Comment: `Get-Date` is just the way PowerShell has to access the `DateTime Struct` in System Namespace. Almost everything (or everything not sure, cmdlets, data structures, classes, types, etc), that is native to PS is from C# / .NET Framework / .NET Core. mklement0 probably can give us a more accurate answer here. But in some sense, yes, `Get-Date` is accessing the `System.DateTime` and helping you manipulate it @AbrahamZinala

Comment: You're welcome, @AbrahamZinala; let me try to phrase it a bit differently: In the expression `(Get-Date) -is [datetime]`, `(Get-Date)` is a _call_ to the `Get-Date` _cmdlet_ and whatever that cmdlet outputs - which happens to be a `[datetime]` instance - becomes the LHS of the `-is` operator. Yes, all objects in PowerShell are instance of .NET types.

Answer (score 4):

It is called the *cast operator*. The official documentation uses this term in  [about_operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators).

> ### Cast operator [ ]
>
> Converts or limits objects to the specified type. If the objects
> cannot be converted, PowerShell generates an error.