# How to get a result from a function

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a function to calculate either a full ISO date (yyyy-W-d, where W is the ISO week number), or just the ISO week number by itself. My function is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67084508/optional-parameter-to-calculate-dates).

I have 2 problems with my code. One is that I do not know how extract either of the results I am after as written above. The other problem is that the second parameter doesn't show when I try to call the function.

This is my current code.

```
Function Get-ISODate {

    Param(
    [datetime]$Date = (Get-Date),
    [bool]$LongFormat
    )

    $DayOfWeek = $Date.DayOfWeek

    If ($DayOfWeek -match "[1-3]") {$Date.AddDays(3)}

    $Year = $Date.Year

    $Week = $(Get-Culture).Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(($Date),[System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule]::FirstFourDayWeek, [DayOfWeek]::Monday)

    $Day = $Date.Day

    If ($LongFormat)
    {
    
        Get-ISODate = $Year + '-W' + $Week + '-' + $Day
            
    } 
    
    Else
    {

        Get-ISODate = 'W' + $Week

    }       

}
```

My expected results would be,

`Get-ISOWeek` returns W16, which is the current ISO week at this time of writing.

`Get-ISOWeek -LongFormat $true` returns 2021-W16-1

`Get-ISOWeek -Date '2000-1-1'` returns W52

`Get-ISOWeek -Date '2000-1-1' -LongFormat $true` returns 1999-W52-6

I'm using this [link](http://myweb.ecu.edu/mccartyr/isowdcal.html) to verifiy my results with regards to the week calculation.

Comment: Remove `Get-ISODate = `

Comment: Thanks. I originally tried that, but don't see any output when I "run" the code. Also, the second parameter still doesn't pop up, just the $Date parameter.

Comment: `[bool]$LongFormat` should be `[switch]$LongFormat` and you ask `If ($LongFormat.IsPresent){ ....`

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean ```If ($LongFormat.IsPresent)``` instead of ```If ($LongFormat)```? I tried that, and also replacing ```[bool]$LongFormatP``` with ```[switch]$LongFormat```, but unfortunately I still have the same problems.

Comment: @Mathias, I see the biggest issue was I wrote the function incorrectly. (using Get-ISOWeek instead of Get-ISODate) You advice worked for the first problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about `switch` paramenter [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.1).

What Mathias meant is to literally remove `Get-ISODate =`

The function should look like this:

```
Function Get-ISODate {
Param(
    [datetime]$Date = (Get-Date),
    [switch]$LongFormat
)

    $DayOfWeek = $Date.DayOfWeek
    
    If ($DayOfWeek -match "[1-3]") {$Date.AddDays(3)}
    
    $Year = $Date.Year
    $Week = $(Get-Culture).Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(($Date),[System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule]::FirstFourDayWeek, [DayOfWeek]::Monday)
    $Day = $Date.Day

    If ($LongFormat.IsPresent)
    {
        return "$Year-W$Week-$Day"    
    } 
    
    'W' + $Week
}

# Testing the function
PS /~> Get-IsoDate
W16

PS /~> Get-IsoDate -LongFormat
2021-W16-19
```

Comment: Thanks Santiago. That works. I planned on using ```Get-ISODate -LongFormat $true```, but with your solution, I don't have to add the ```$true``` part.

Answer (score 0):

Got this working. Please note that the main issue was that I was trying to call the function incorrectly with "Get-ISOWeek". Monday morning.

I also added .value__ to Day for $Day to get the number instead of the day as "Monday" etc.

```
Function Get-ISODate {

    Param(
    [datetime]$Date = (Get-Date),
    [bool]$LongFormat
    )

    $DayOfWeek = $Date.DayOfWeek

    If ($DayOfWeek -match "[1-3]") {$Date.AddDays(3)}

    $Year = $Date.Year

    $Week = $(Get-Culture).Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(($Date),[System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule]::FirstFourDayWeek, [DayOfWeek]::Monday)

    $Day = $Date.DayOfWeek.value__

    If ($LongFormat -eq $true)
    {
    
        "$Year-W$Week-$Day"            
    } 
    
    Else
    {

        "W$Week"

    }       

}
```

Edit: I realised after posting this, the year was sometimes wrong according to the week number and day of the week. So here is my new version. I have checked the dates [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).

```
Function Get-ISODate {

    Param(
    [datetime]$Date = (Get-Date),
    [switch]$LongFormat
    )

    [int]$Year = $Date.Year

    [int]$Month = $Date.Month

    [int]$Day = $Date.DayOfWeek.value__

    If ($Day -eq 0) {$Day = 7}

    If ($Day -ge 1 -and $Day -le 3) {$Date = $Date.AddDays(3)}

    $Week = (Get-Culture).Calendar.GetWeekOfYear($Date, 'FirstFourDayWeek', 'Monday')

    Switch ($Week)
    {

        52 {If ($Day -ge 5 -and $Day -le 7 -and $Month -ne 12) {$Year = $Year - 1} ; Break}

        53  {If ($Day -ge 5 -and $Day -le 7 -and $Month -ne 12) {$Year = $Year - 1} ; Break}

        1 {If ($Month -eq 12) {$Year = $Year + 1} ; Break}

    }

    $Week = $Week.ToString('00')

    If ($LongFormat.IsPresent)
    {
    
        "$Year-W$Week-$Day"  
                  
    } 
    
    Else
    {

        "W$Week"

    }       

}
```