# How can I import/load a .dll file to use in a PowerShell script without getting "TypeNotFound" error?

Tags: powershell, dll, dllimport

```
 [void] CreateSession() {
    try {
        # Load WinSCP .NET assembly
        Add-Type -Path (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "\winscp\WinSCPnet.dll")
        # Setup session options
        $this.sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
            Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
```

In the above section of code I encounter the "TypeNotFound" error message regarding "[WinSCP.Protocol]".

```
  14 |                  Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
     |                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Unable to find type [WinSCP.Protocol].
```

The .dll file can load correctly, I have verified this previously. I know what is happening is that the PowerShell "parser" is throwing an error because it doesn't recognize the WinSCP library at load time. I have tried adding a module and manifest, but I cannot find a simple example of how to do this properly. Also, it doesn't matter if I'm running PowerShell 5.x or 7.x. All I am wanting is to load this DLL so I can use classes/functions from it. Why is loading a DLL so hard in PowerShell?

What do I need to do to get this WinSCP DLL to load at runtime and not throw an error?

### Note on possible duplicates

A very similar question was asked on this site a couple years ago by someone, but there are no answers to it.

### Note on suggested duplicate

I am looking for a real example for how to load a DLL file into a script. The linked question does not appropriately do that. Why do I need to create a manifest module thing to import the DLL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

- The problem stems from trying to reference the just-loaded WinSCP types *in a `class` definition*, via [*type literals*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66996505/45375), such as `[WinSCP.Protocol]`, as explained below.
- The problem can be *bypassed* by not using `class`es at all, and using [*functions*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions) instead.

---

> I am looking for a real example for how to load a DLL file into a script.

[`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type) `-Path` / `-LiteralPath`, as shown in your code does just that:

It loads the specified .NET assembly and makes its public types available in the calling session, just like the similar [`using assembly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_using) statement.

However, since you're using a [`class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes) definition
attempting to reference a type from an assembly you are loading *from the same script file* via a *type literal* (e.g, `[WinSCP.Protocol]`), the class definition *fails*:

**At script-file *parse time*, all types being referenced by a `class` definition as *type literals* (e.g. `[WinSCP.Protocol]`)** - whether as *property types*, in the *body of methods*, or as a *base class* / *interface to implement* (though in the latter case the type literal has no `[...]` enclosure; e.g. `class Foo : WinSCP.Protocol { ... }`)  -
***must already have been loaded into the session***, as of PowerShell 7.3.6.<sup>[1]</sup>

- Removing this counterintuitive requirement for the `using assembly` statement was green-lit in 2017, but hasn't been implemented as of this writing: see [GitHub issue #3641](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3641#issuecomment-297151112).

**Workarounds**:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42839957/45375) offers two solutions:

  - A (multi-file) [module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules)-based solution.
  - A (suboptimal) [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression)-based solution.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77936848/45375) offers a simple *two-script* solution:

  - One script that loads the dependent assembly first, and then [dot-sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) another that contains the `class` definition based on the dependent assembly's types.

---

A **workaround isn't always needed**, namely **if you avoid use of [*type literals*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66996505/45375), such as `[WinSCP.Protocol]`**

- With respect to `[WinSCP.SessionOptions]`, you're already doing that by using [`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object) `WinSCP.SessionOptions` instead of the more modern (PSv5+) `[WinSCP.SessionOptions]::new()`
- You can also avoid it for the `[WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp` enumeration value by simply using a *string* - `'Sftp'` instead - at least for the code snippet shown this would solve your problem; here's a simplified example:

```bash
class Foo {
  # Note: Do NOT use [WinSCP.SessionOptions] here.
  [object] $sessionOptions 
  [void] CreateSession() {
      # Load WinSCP .NET assembly
      Add-Type -LiteralPath (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "\winscp\WinSCPnet.dll")
      # Set up session options
      # Note the use of *string* 'Sftp' in lieu of [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
      $this.sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
        Protocol = 'Sftp'  
      }
  }
}
```

Now you can instantiate `[Foo]` as you normally would - either with `New-Object Foo` or, preferable with `[Foo]::new()` (once `[Foo]` itself is successfully defined, it's fine to refer to *it* by a type literal, *outside* `class` definitions).

---

<sup>[1] Classes were a relatively late addition to the PowerShell language, and, unfortunately, there are still many problems to be worked out - see the list of pending issues in [GitHub issue #6652](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6652). Note, however, that feature parity with, say, C# classes was never the aim.</sup>

Answer (score -2):

The easiest solution, and the one I have resolved to use, is to just use functions and not classes in PowerShell.

Just use functions, not classes in PowerShell.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: PowerShell do support using classes as well. But that wasn't the question...