# Problems Using System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox inside Class

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-5.0

First, the code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
class Preferences {
    hidden [string]$_PrefPath
    hidden [string]$_installLocation
    hidden [int]$_maxAttempts
    hidden [boolean]$_silent
    hidden [string]$_skippedVersion


    Preferences(
        [string]$p
    ){
        $this._PrefPath = $p
        If (-not ([preferences]::PrefsExistAndNotNull($p))) {
            [preferences]::InitPref($p)
        }
        $this.LoadVals()
    }

    Preferences (
        [string]$p,
        [boolean]$s
    ){
        If (-not ([preferences]::PrefsExistAndNotNull($p)) -and $s) {
            throw "No registry config found, silence precludes requesting install location"
        } elseif (-not ([preferences]::PrefsExistAndNotNull($p)) -and -not $s) {
            [preferences]::InitPref($p)
        }
        $this._silent = $s
        $this._PrefPath = $p
        $this.LoadVals()
    }

    hidden static [boolean]PrefsExistAndNotNull([string]$p){
        if (-not (Test-Path $p)) {
            return $false
        }
        if (-not (Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $p -Name PathToKoL -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
            return $false
        }
        if ( [string]::IsNullOrEmpty((Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $p -Name PathToKoL)) ) {
            return $false
        }
        return $true
    }

    hidden static [void]InitPref([string]$p){
        if (-not
                (Test-Path $p) -and -not
                (Test-Path ($p | Split-Path))
        ) {
            New-Item ($p | Split-Path)
            Write-Verbose "Creating key at $($p | Split-Path)"
        }
        if (-not (Test-Path $p)) {
            New-Item $p
            Write-Verbose "Creating key at $p"
        }
        try {
            $needtoask = [string]::IsNullOrEmpty((Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $p -Name PathToKoL -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
        } catch {
            $needtoask = $true
        }
        if ($needtoask) {
            $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
            $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $env:USERPROFILE
            $OpenFileDialog.filter = “JAR files (*.jar)| *.jar”
            $OpenFileDialog.Title = "Select Location of KolMafia JAR"
            $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
            $askfordir = [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($OpenFileDialog.FileName)
            if (-not $askfordir) {
                $installLocation = $OpenFileDialog.filename | Split-Path -Parent
                New-ItemProperty -Path $p -Name 'PathToKoL' -Value $installLocation -PropertyType String
                Write-Verbose "Creating value PathToKoL at $p"
            }
        } else {
            $askfordir = $false
        }
        if ($askfordir) {
            $msg = "No file was selected. Should Launcher assume you don't have KoLMafia installed and ask where you want it? (Selecting No will exit immediately)"
            $title = 'No file selected'
            $buttons = 4 #[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::YesNo
            $nobutton = 7 #[System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::No
            $icon = 32 #[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Question
            $default = 0 #[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxDefaultButton]::Button1
            $options = 0
            $answer = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($msg,$title,$buttons,$icon,$default,$options)
            if ($answer -eq $nobutton) {
                EXIT 0
            }  else {
                $SelectFolderDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
                $SelectFolderDialog.SelectedPath = $env:USERPROFILE
                $SelectFolderDialog.Description = "Select where you want to install KoLMafia"
                $SelectFolderDialog.ShowNewFolderButton = $true
                $SelectFolderDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
                if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($SelectFolderDialog.SelectedPath)) {
                    EXIT 0
                } else {
                    $installLocation = $SelectFolderDialog.SelectedPath
                    New-ItemProperty -Path $p -Name 'PathToKoL' -Value $installLocation -PropertyType String
                    Write-Verbose "Creating value PathToKoL at $p"
                }
            }
        }
        try {
            Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $p -Name MaxDownloadAttempts | Out-Null
        } catch {
            New-ItemProperty -Path $p -Name 'MaxDownloadAttempts' -Value 3 -PropertyType Dword
            Write-Verbose "Creating value MaxDownloadAttempts at $p"
        }
        try {
            Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $p -Name SkippedVersion | Out-Null
        } catch {
            New-ItemProperty -Path $p -Name 'SkippedVersion' -Value '' -PropertyType String
            Write-Verbose "Creating value SkippedVersion at $p"
        }
    }

    hidden [void]LoadVals(){
        If (-not ([preferences]::PrefsExistAndNotNull($this._PrefPath))) {
            [preferences]::InitPref($this._PrefPath)
        }
        $this._installLocation = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $this._PrefPath -Name PathToKoL
        $this._maxAttempts = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $this._PrefPath -Name MaxDownloadAttempts
        try {
            Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $this._PrefPath -Name SkippedVersion | Out-Null
        } catch {
            New-ItemProperty -Path $this._PrefPath -Name 'SkippedVersion' -Value '' -PropertyType String
            Write-Verbose "Creating value SkippedVersion at $($this._PrefPath)"
        } finally {
            $this._skippedVersion = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $this._PrefPath -Name SkippedVersion
        }
    }

    [string]GetLocation(){
        return $this._installLocation
    }

    [void]SetLocation([string]$p){
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $this._PrefPath -Name PathToKoL -Value $p
        $this._installLocation = $p
    }

    [int]GetMaxAttempts(){
        return $this._maxAttempts
    }

    [void]SetMaxAttempts([int]$m){
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $this._PrefPath -Name MaxDownloadAttempts -Value $m
        $this._maxAttempts = $m
    }

    [string]GetSkippedVersion(){
        return $this._skippedVersion
    }

    [void]SetSkippedVersion([string]$v){
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $this._PrefPath -Name SkippedVersion -Value $v
        $this._skippedVersion = $v
    }
}

Function Get-ShellOpenFromExtention {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Extension
    )
    begin {
        if ($Extension -notmatch '\.?(?<Extension>[a-z0-9]{1,3}$)') {
            return $null
        }
        $Extension = -join('.', $Matches.Extension)
    }
    process {
        try {
            $RegisteredApplication = (Get-ItemProperty "Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\$Extension" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).'(default)'
            if ($null -eq $RegisteredApplication) {return $null}
            $ShellOpen = (Get-ItemProperty "Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\$RegisteredApplication\shell\open\command" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).'(default)'
        } catch {
            return $null
        }
        if ($null -eq $ShellOpen) {return $null}
        $ShellOpen = $ShellOpen.Replace(' %*','')
        if ($shellOpen -match '(?(^")(?<path>"[^"]*")|(?<path>[^ ]*)) (?<params>.*)') {
            return @{
                appPath = $Matches.path
                arguments = $Matches.params
            }
        }
    }
    end {
        return $null
    }
}
```

So that code has been working for weeks.  Suddenly, it has stopped working, and I'm not sure why.

Specifically, I get errors at

```
At C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\GitHub\KoLMafia-Launcher\SOURCE\Launch-KoLMafia.ps1:90 char:25
+ ...            $buttons = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::YesNo
+                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unable to find type [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons].
At C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\GitHub\KoLMafia-Launcher\SOURCE\Launch-KoLMafia.ps1:91 char:26
+             $nobutton = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::No
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unable to find type [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult].
At C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\GitHub\KoLMafia-Launcher\SOURCE\Launch-KoLMafia.ps1:92 char:22
+             $icon = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Question
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unable to find type [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon].
At C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\GitHub\KoLMafia-Launcher\SOURCE\Launch-KoLMafia.ps1:93 char:25
+ ...      $default = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxDefaultButton]::Butto ...
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unable to find type [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxDefaultButton].
At C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\GitHub\KoLMafia-Launcher\SOURCE\Launch-KoLMafia.ps1:95 char:24
+             $answer = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($msg,$t ...
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unable to find type [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox].
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

I call MessageBox elsewhere, and it works, so it has to have something to do with trying to call it within the class above.  And I call OpenFileDialog within the Class, so it has the System.Windows.Forms assembly available within the class - its just the MessageBox class that seems to be problematic.

Comment: Your answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837447/powershell-unable-to-find-type-when-using-ps-5-classes/67881570 // easiest way to solve it is to have a file that will load the assembly separately from your class file

Comment: I think @Santiago is correct; a more succinct summary can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69104097/45375).