# Task: Show a custom DialogBox with big text + loud alarm sound and a close button via PowerShell script

Tags: windows, powershell, winforms

I want to display a custom dialog with a big text + a button (to close the window) + an alarm via PowerShell script.

To show the dialog box and to sound the alarm at the same time was no problem, but I just cannot add the button below the label.

Note: I completly do not understand the PowerShell language. The complete script was stiched together via trial and error with the help of ChatGpt 3.5, but it just cannot place the button below the label. It either produces invalid code or the button is not being displayed at all.

Here is the script:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# Create a user-defined form class
class CustomMessageBox : System.Windows.Forms.Form {
    CustomMessageBox([string]$title, [string]$message) {
        $this.Text = $title
        $this.ClientSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1500, 400)  # Adjust the form size

        # Show a label with big text
        $label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
        $label.Text = $message
        $label.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 56, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
        $label.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::TopCenter
        $label.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Fill 

        # create an 'OK' button
        $okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
        $okButton.Text = "OK"
        $okButton.Add_Click({
            # Schließe die Form, wenn der OK-Button geklickt wird
            $this.Close()
        })

        $this.Controls.Add($label)
        $this.Controls.Add($okButton)

        # center on the screen
        $this.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen
    }
}

$title = "Alarm! Dinner is ready."
$popupMessage = "We can now eat dinner, Peter.`nPlease come down."

# Specify the path to your alarm sound file
$alarmSoundPath = "C:\Users\Nils\Documents\Powershell\digital-clock-beep-989.wav"

# Check if the sound file exists
if (Test-Path $alarmSoundPath) {
    # start a background job for playing the alarm
    $alarmJob = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
        param($path)
        $alarmPlayer = New-Object System.Media.SoundPlayer
        $alarmPlayer.SoundLocation = $path
        while ($true) {
            $alarmPlayer.PlaySync()
        }
    } -ArgumentList $alarmSoundPath

    $customMessageBox = [CustomMessageBox]::new($title, $popupMessage)
    $null = $customMessageBox.ShowDialog()

    # Terminate the background job after closing the MessageBox
    Stop-Job $alarmJob
} else {
    Write-Host "Alarm sound file not found. Please provide a valid path."
}
```

## Question:

How can the script be fixed to show the OK button below the label of the custom alarm dialog box?

## What did you try and what were you expecting?

I added the ok button to the controls of the custom form class and I expected the button to be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The primary problem is that **your label control is made to fill up the *entire client area* of the form**, which means that the OK button is effectively *hidden*.

  - The **solution is to size and place both the label and the button explicitly**, in relation to each other; the code below does that, via the [`.Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Windows.Forms.Control.Location) property in combination with the [`.AutoSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label.autosize), [`.Size`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Windows.Forms.Control.Size) and [`.ClientSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Windows.Forms.Control.ClientSize) properties (more sophisticated approaches involving additional controls, such as [`[System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel), are possible).
- Secondary problems:

  - **In event-handler script blocks, the [automatic `$this` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#this) refers to the *event sender***, i.e the OK button in your case, and *not* to the enclosing `class` instance.

    - `$this.FindForm()` allows you to find the latter (the `Form`-derived class instance), so you can call its `.Close()` method.
  - Unfortunately, **calling `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms` *as part of your script* is *too late*** for the script to be able to reference that assembly's types in your custom `class` definition (as of PowerShell 7.4.1, this unfortunately applies equally to using `using assembly System.Windows.Forms` instead - see [GitHub issue #18482](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18482)).

    - In your case, **a *two-script* solution is simplest**:

      - Create a helper `Classes.ps1` script that contains the `class` definition.
      - Create a `Main.ps1` script that first calls `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms` to ensure that the assembly is loaded and then [*dot-sources*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) `Classes.ps1` in order to load the `class` definition:

To put it all together (alarm sound-playing code omitted for brevity):

- `Main.ps1`:

```bash
# Load the WinForms assemblies.
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# Now dot-source the helper script that contains the class definition.
. (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot Classes.ps1)

# Now create and show the custom form.
$title = "Alarm! Dinner is ready."
$popupMessage = "We can now eat dinner, Peter.`nPlease come down."

$customMessageBox = [CustomMessageBox]::new($title, $popupMessage)
$null = $customMessageBox.ShowDialog()
```

- `Classes.ps1` (place in the same directory):

```bash
# IMPORTANT:
#    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
# must have been called BEFORE invoking this script.

using namespace System.Windows.Forms
using namespace System.Drawing

# Create a user-defined form class
class CustomMessageBox : Form {
    static [Font] $CustomFont = [Font]::new("Arial", 56, [FontStyle]::Bold)
    CustomMessageBox([string]$title, [string]$message) {
        $this.Text = $title
        $this.ClientSize = New-Object Size(1500, 400)  # Adjust the form size
        $this.StartPosition = [FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen # Center the form on the screen
        # Make sure that the form receives focus when it is displayed.
        $this.add_Shown({ $this.Activate() })

        # Create a label with big text.
        $label = [Label]::new()
        $label.Text = $message
        $label.Font = [CustomMessageBox]::CustomFont
        $label.TextAlign = [ContentAlignment]::TopCenter
        $label.AutoSize = $true

        # Create an 'OK' button
        $okButton = [Button]::new()
        $okButton.Font = [CustomMessageBox]::CustomFont
        $okButton.Text = "OK"
        $okButton.AutoSize = $true
        # Add an event handler
        $okButton.Add_Click({
          # Note:
          #  $this here refers to the *button* object, not to the form.
          #  .FindForm() can be used to find the enclosing form.
          $this.FindForm().Close()
        })

        # Add the controls to the form.
        $this.Controls.Add($label)
        $this.Controls.Add($okButton)

        # Only now, after having added the controls, does .AutoSize = $true 
        # take effect, so determine the controls' locations only now.
        $label.Location = @{ 
          X = ($this.ClientSize.Width - $label.Size.Width) / 2
          Y = 0 
        }
        $okButton.Location = @{
          X = ($this.ClientSize.Width - $okButton.Size.Width) / 2
          Y = $label.Location.Y + $label.Size.Height + 20
        }

    }
}
```