# How to load the classes in PowerShell module globally?

Tags: powershell, class, types, powershell-core, powershell-7.4

I've already read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837447/powershell-unable-to-find-type-when-using-ps-5-classes) and even though it has lots of back and forth, I tried my best to follow the suggestions, but still not sure how to work around this.

I have defined multiple classes in the `ScriptsToProcess` `.ps1` file like this:

https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/blob/WDACConfig-v0.3.4/WDACConfig/WDACConfig%20Module%20Files/Preloader.ps1

The problem is that when I install the module in a clean state VM (where the module never existed before) and try to use the cmdlets, I get an error saying the type is not found, but if I close and reopen PowerShell or use `Import-Module` with `-Force` parameter then everything is okay.

I need to know how I can work around this problem without introducing too many repetitive code.

I'm using PowerShell 7.5

- [The module root folder](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/tree/WDACConfig-v0.3.4/WDACConfig/WDACConfig%20Module%20Files)
- [Module manifest](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/blob/WDACConfig-v0.3.4/WDACConfig/WDACConfig%20Module%20Files/WDACConfig.psd1)
- [VS code workspace for easy debugging is here if needed](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/tree/WDACConfig-v0.3.4/WDACConfig)

Comment: Can you share the module manifest?

Comment: To what folder did you copy the modules? They should go into a folder specified by `$ENV:PSModulePath`

Comment: Ok, so you are copying the module to `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`. Are the components properly labeled? I.e. the module file has the exact same name as the module folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand the VM-related problem, but perhaps the following approach *bypasses* the problem:

- Define your [`class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes)es as part of your script's root module (`*.psm1`, referenced via the `RootModule` module-manifest entry) instead of your current approach of using a  `*.ps1` file that is loaded into the caller's scope via the  `ScriptsToProcess` manifest entry.

  - In other words: you then won't need a `ScriptsToProcess` entry (at least not for exporting your `class`es and `enum`s).
- By itself, this makes your classes only available to callers that import the module with a parse-time **[`using module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Using#module-syntax)** statement, but note the following:

  - The linked documentation notes (emphasis added):

    > [`using module`] doesn't consistently import classes or enumerations defined in nested modules or in scripts that are dot-sourced into the root module. *Define classes and enumerations that you want to be available to users outside of the module directly in the root module*.
  - Only the importer and its descendent scopes see the imported module's `class`es (and [`enum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Enum)s).
  - Because `using module` is a parse-time statement, the target module path must not contain variables, but modules discoverable via `$env:PSModulePath` can be referenced by name only (e.g. `using module MyModule`); *relative* paths are resolved against the caller's own file-system location (rather than against the current directory).
  - Once a module is imported with `using module` in a given session, it cannot be forcefully re-imported; that is, if you want to *modify* your `class` and/or `enum` definitions, you'll need to start a new session to see the changes.
- However, the [Exporting classes with **type accelerators**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes#exporting-classes-with-type-accelerators) section of the [about_Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes) help topic  describes a **workaround** that **makes classes of your choice available *session-globally***, in all scopes and runspaces, and also works with module [*auto-loading*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules#module-autoloading) and [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module)
- The sample code below demonstrates this approach, but comes with the following **caveats**:

  - As with the `using module`-based approach, you won't be able to *reload* modified `class` definitions in a given session - start a new session instead.
  - Unlike with the `using module`-based approach (which you may still choose to *combine* with the suggested approach), the (possibly implicit) importer must not rely on the `class`es to be available *at parse time*, i.e. must not try to reference them via type literals in `class` definition of its own - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69104097/45375) for details.

    - While the type-accelerator approach technically allows you to place the `class` and `enum` definitions in a *nested* module or a `*.ps1` file dot-sourced from your root module, this is best avoided if you want your module to also support the `using module` importing technique for parse-time availability of the classes.
  - Because the suggested approach (potentially) exposes the `class`es to *other runspaces* too, they should be decorated with the **[`[NoRunspaceAffinity()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Language.NoRunspaceAffinityAttribute)** attribute, which is available in **v7.4+** only. That said, the approach is safe to use in earlier versions as long as only a *single* runspace (the default runspace) is used.
  - The linked help topic also includes event-based code for attempting to *remove* exported `class` definitions when the module is unloaded (`Remove-Module`), however, this does *not* work (as of PowerShell 7.4.1), and has therefore been omitted in the code below.

Note that with either approach above, `class`es and `enum`s won't be available until after your module has been imported into a given session.
That is, unlike *functions and cmdlets* in auto-loading modules, they aren't discoverable prior to import.

Example `*.psm1` root-module content:

```bash
# Since the quasi-exported class will be available *process-wide*
# and therefore also in *other runspaces*, be sure to define it with
# the [NoRunspaceAffinity()] attribute.
# Caveat: **v7.4+ only**
[NoRunspaceAffinity()]
class SomeClass { # Note: 'SomeClass' is both its .Name and .FullName.
  [int] Get() { return 42 }
}

# Define the types to export with type accelerators.
# Note: Unlike the `using module` approach, this approach allows
#       you to *selectively* export `class`es and `enum`s.
$exportableTypes = @(
  [SomeClass]
)

# Get the non-public TypeAccelerators class for defining new accelerators.
$typeAcceleratorsClass = [psobject].Assembly.GetType('System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators')

# Add type accelerators for every exportable type.
$existingTypeAccelerators = $typeAcceleratorsClass::Get
foreach ($type in $exportableTypes) {
  # !! $TypeAcceleratorsClass::Add() quietly ignores attempts to redefine existing
  # !! accelerators with different target types, so we check explicitly.
  $existing = $existingTypeAccelerators[$type.FullName]
  if ($null -ne $existing -and $existing -ne $type) {
    throw "Unable to register type accelerator [$($type.FullName)], because it is already defined with a different type ([$existing])."
  }
  $typeAcceleratorsClass::Add($type.FullName, $type)
}
```

Any (possibly implicit) importer of the module associated with this `*.psm1` will have the `[SomeClass]` class available to them *at runtime*.

That is, `[SomeClass]::new().Get()` in the caller's scope and any scope thereafter should yield `42`

Comment: Thanks, I put the classes in a `.psm1` file and imported it via `Using Module` in a nested module. It worked but I think it requires extra care to pay attention to the path since it doesn't support variables. I use a variable for the module's root path so that instead of .\ or ..\ and so on I can just use the variable and prevent accidentally pointing to a non-existent file when working with nested folder structure.

Comment: As for the 2nd method you suggested, it's working really well! I used the `Import-Module` in `ScriptsToProcess` to import that `.psm1` file containing that logic (also moved my class definition there too) and it is now available globally to the entire module. Since my module already requires latest PS version this is not an issue. I'm going to only use this method. Thanks again! 

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @SpyNet; my pleasure. Yes, because `using module` is a _parse-time_ statement, variable references in module paths aren't supported.

Comment: @SpyNet: As for the type-accelerator solution: you don't actually need `ScriptsToProcess` with this approach.  I suggest placing your classes and the export code directly into your project's root module. While the type-accelerator approach would also support placing them in nested modules or scripts that you dot-source directly from your root module, only placing them in the root module predictably surfaces them _at parse time_ when your module is used with `using module`. I've updated the answer to clarify all those points.

Comment: Thank you, I want to keep all of the classes separate in their own `.psm1` file but I'm now importing them into the root module like this `Import-Module -FullyQualifiedName "$ModuleRootPath\CoreExt\Classes.psm1" -Force`