# How to reference PSCredential.Empty in powershell script

Tags: powershell, syntax, static-members

I am trying to use empty credentials for anonymous access.  How to I set a variable to empty credentials.  I am trying to use [PSCredential.Empty Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscredential.empty?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0)

Comment: Just like this `$cred = [pscredential]::Empty`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) has provided the solution:

```
[pscredential]::Empty
```

is the PowerShell equivalent of C#'s `PSCredential.Empty`, i.e. access to the static `Empty` property of the [`System.Management.Automation.PSCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSCredential) type.

---

**PowerShell's syntax for accessing .NET types and their - instance or static - member:**

- In order to refer to a .NET type by its literal name in PowerShell, you must specify it as a *type literal*, which is the **type name *enclosed in* `[...]`**

  - `[pscredential]` works as-is, even in the absence of a 
    [`using namespace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Using#namespace-syntax) `System.Management.Automation` statement, because it happens to be a [type *accelerator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Accelerators), i.e. a frequently used type that you can access by a short, unqualified name (which can, but needn't be the same name as that of the type it references; e.g., `[xml]` is short for `System.Xml.XmlDocument`).
  - Generally, you either need a `using namespace` statement if you want to use the unqualified *name* only, or you need to use the *namespace-qualified* type name; e.g., `[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]` or - given that the `System.` component is optional - `[Management.Automation.PSCredential]`
  - For a complete discussion of PowerShell's type literals, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66996505/45375).
- While ***instance* members** of .NET types are accessed **with `.`** ([member-access operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#member-access-operator-)), just like in C#, accessing ***static* members** requires a ***different* operator: `::`**, the [static member-access operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#static-member-operator-).

  - A distinct operator is necessary, because type literals are *objects themselves*, namely instances of [`System.Reflection.TypeInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Reflection.TypeInfo), so that using `.` accesses the *latter's* instance properties; e.g. `[pscredential].FullName` returns the type's namespace-qualified name.

Also note that, in keeping with PowerShell's general **case-*insensitive*** nature, neither type literals nor member names need be specified case-exactly.