# What is the proper way to use Import-Excel to import numbers and then use the PSObjects as numbers?

Tags: powershell

I import data from an Excel spreadsheet. The data are all numbers like 123.12345678. I can import the data Into an array That is a PowerShell object, but I cannot figure out how to get the data back into a number. For example, I need to be able to do something like $MyArray[0] = $MyArray + 100. That throws an error for no method.

I start with,

```
$MyArray = New-Object 'object()' # to import one column and New-Object 'object(,)'for two columns.
$MyArray = Import-Excel C:\\Scripts\\whatever.xlsx -WorksheetName Calculations -NoHeader -StartRow 91 -EndRow 101 -StartColumn 35 -EndColumn 35
```

$MyArray has ten entries that are PSObjects. Even after much looking on StackOverflow I am confused as to how to get a number that is a real number.

Answer (score 2):

`Import-Excel` imports numbers as `double`, a column containing only numeric digits is represented as a `double`, the following demonstrates it:

```bash
0..10 | ForEach-Object { [pscustomobject]@{ Column1 = $_ } } |
    Export-Excel .\test.xlsx -WorksheetName test

Import-Excel test.xlsx -WorksheetName test |
    Get-Member

#    TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
# 
# Name        MemberType   Definition
# ----        ----------   ----------
# Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
# GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
# GetType     Method       type GetType()
# ToString    Method       string ToString()
# Column1     NoteProperty double Column1=0

Import-Excel test.xlsx -WorksheetName test |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Column1.GetType() } |
    Select-Object -First 1

#   Namespace: System
#
# Access        Modifiers           Name
# ------        ---------           ----
# public        readonly struct     double : ValueType, IComparable, IConvertible...
```

It seems that what you're missing is expanding the values of your column, in other words, dot notation as shown in the example above with `$_.Column1` for example.

---

From OP's feedback in comments:

> I can not get my head around this. I still can not get this to work. Could you show me a code snippet from declaring an array to picking a value and adding 100 to it? I'm bewildered.

Hope this helps:

```bash
0..5 | ForEach-Object { [pscustomobject]@{ Column1 = $_ } } |
    Export-Excel .\test.xlsx -WorksheetName test

$xlsx = Import-Excel .\test.xlsx
$xlsx

# Column1
# -------
#    0.00
#    1.00
#    2.00
#    3.00
#    4.00
#    5.00

# lets add `100` to the value of `Column1` in the thrid row
# (index in .NET languages starts at 0, so index 2 is the third)
$xlsx[2].Column1 += 100
$xlsx

# Column1
# -------
#    0.00
#    1.00
#  102.00
#    3.00
#    4.00
#    5.00

# lets update a row with a predicate, say for example,
# add `100` the row having a value of `5.00` in `Column1`
$xlsx |
    Where-Object Column1 -EQ 5.00 |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Column1 += 100 }

$xlsx

# Column1
# -------
#    0.00
#    1.00
#  102.00
#    3.00
#    4.00
#  105.00
```

Comment: For some reason I just can not get my head

Comment: I can not get my head around this.  I still can not get this to work. Could you show me a code snippet from declaring an array to picking a value and adding 100 to it? I'm bewildered.

Comment: @gurneyr see my update, hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

As implied by [Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77467295/45375), **what [`Import-Excel`](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel#readme) returns** is:

- *not* a *two-dimensional array of values*, as you seem to expect,
- but a ***one-dimensional array* of [`[pscustombject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_PSCustomObject) instances, with each element representing a *row of cells* in the requested range**.

The **column *values* of each such *row*-representing `[pscustomobject]` must be accessed via the latter's *properties***, which correspond to the implied or chosen column *names*:

- by default: the column names are implied by the *first* row of the targeted range.

  - That is, the property *names* are determined by the first row, and all subsequent rows become *values* of these properties.
  - To put it differently: the first row in the input range is used solely to determine the property names for the `[pscustomobject]` instances returned, and only all *subsequent* rows are considered *data*, namely the property *values* of these instances.
- alternatively:

  - `-NoHeader`: the specified range is considered *data only*, and property names are *auto-generated*, namely as `P1`, `P2`, ...
  - `-HeaderName`: the specified range is considered *data only*, and the property (column) names are the *specified ones* (e.g. `-HeaderName foo, bar, baz`)

Applied to your use case:

```bash
$MyArray = Import-Excel C:\Scripts\whatever.xlsx -WorksheetName Calculations -NoHeader -StartRow 91 -EndRow 101 -StartColumn 35 -EndColumn 35
```

The above returns:

- a 11-element array of `[pscustomobject]` instances (the row range of `91` through `101` comprises 11 rows)
- with *one* property each (`-StartColumn` has the same value as `-EndColumn`), whose name is `P1` (auto-named, given that you used `-NoHeader`)

Using [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration), you can retrieve the property (cell) *values* as follows:

```bash
$MyValue.P1
```

To retrieve the *first* row's value, for instance, use `$MyValue[0].P1`

As Santiago notes, cells that contain *numbers* in Excel are imported as `[double]` instances.

Separately, your question exhibits several misconceptions about PowerShell itself, as discussed in the next section.

---

Your question exemplifies several **misconceptions**:

> `C:\\Scripts\\whatever.xlsx`

**`\` (a backslash)** has ***no* special meaning in PowerShell**, so there's **never a need to use `\\` in file-system paths** in order to escape `\` chars.
**PowerShell's [escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) is `` ` ``**, the so-called *backtick*.

---

> `New-Object 'object()'`
> `New-Object 'object(,)'`
> `New-Object 'object(foo, bar, baz)'`

**Whatever follows `(` - which isn't proper syntax - is *quietly ignored*** in these [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item) calls - which is a ***bug* in *Windows PowerShell* and [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) *up to v7.3.x*** (fixed in v7.4+, which now sensibly reports an *error*).
That is, all in these versions all of these calls are the same as `New-Object object` aka `[object]::new()` in v5+

To **create *arrays*, use `[...]`**, which **requires a *constructor argument* for each dimension**; e.g.:

```bash
New-Object object[] 2        # one-dimensional array: same as [object[]]::new(2)
New-Object object[,] 2, 3    # two-dimensional array: RARE in PowerShell
```

---

> `$MyArray = ...`

**Such a [variable assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Assignment_Operators) does *not* lock in a specific *data type*** for the variable being assigned to.
Any subsequent assignment is free to assign a value of a *different type*.

- This means that your (flawed) `$MyArray = New-Object 'object()'` assignment was both unnecessary and *irrelevant*, because the next `$MyArray = ...` assignment simply *overrode it*.

To **lock in a data type, use a *type constraint***, which means placing a *cast* to the *left* of  the assignment target; e.g.:

```bash
[int[]] $intArray = 1..3
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66996505/45375) for more information.