# Convert C# URI to Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

In C#:

```
        #region GetCleanDomainName
        private static string GetCleanDomainName( string url ) {

            string cleanURL = string.Empty;

            if (Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, out Uri? NewUri)) {
                cleanURL = NewUri.Authority;
            }
            return cleanURL;
        }
        #endregion
```

I would like to convert to Powershell:

```
[string]$url = "https://stackoverflow.com/bla/another_directory/somepage.aspx"

$cleanURL

if([System.Uri]::TryCreate($url, [System.UriKind]::Absolute, [ref][System.Uri]$NewUri)) {
    $cleanURL=([System.Uri]$NewUri).Authority
}
Write-Host $url`n
Write-Host $cleanURL`n
```

I am hoping to see these results. Although, only interested in the latter:

https://stackoverflow.com/bla/another_directory/somepage.aspx
stackoverflow.com

On this site, it says to convert OUT to [ref], which I did but I get some sort of error that $NewUrl is not defined.

Where am I going wrong and how to correct it?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I can always create a Cmdlet with the above C# code and use Powershell around it.

Comment: Initialize `$NewUri` with `$null` and then use `[ref]$NewUri`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Abdul Niyas P M](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77934769/45375) has provided the crucial pointers:

- Initialize `$NewUri` to `$null`
- Pass it as `[ref] $NewUri` (no additional type cast) to the `out` parameter of [`[System.Uri]::TryCreate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Uri.TryCreate)

Applied to a version of your code that has been made more PowerShell-idiomatic:

```bash
# Note: Type-constraining your $url variable with [string] is optional.
[string] $url = "https://stackoverflow.com/bla/another_directory/somepage.aspx"

# Create the variable that will be used with [ref].
# You *must* assign a value, in order to create a variable, but what 
# that value is irrelevant. 
# You may type-constrain the variable, but that won't gain you much.
$NewUri = $null

# Assign the result  of the `if` statement to the result variable.
# If the `if` block isn't entered, $cleanUrl will effectively be $null.
$cleanURL =
  # Pass [ref] $NewUri to make $NewUri receive the `out` parameter value.
  if ([uri]::TryCreate($url, [UriKind]::Absolute, [ref] $NewUri)) {
    ([uri] $NewUri).Authority
  }

# Diagnostic output.
"$url`n"
"$cleanURL`n"
```

Speaking of PowerShell-idiomatic: With the help of `-as`, the [conditional type conversion operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Operators), and knowing that you expect an *absolute* URI string as input, your code can be reduced to this:

```bash
$url = "https://stackoverflow.com/bla/another_directory/somepage.aspx"

# * -as [uri] will return a [uri] (System.Uri) instance if the
#   input string can be parsed as such, otherwise $null
# * Attempting to access a property on $null is quietly tolerated by
#   default and results in $null too.
$cleanUrl = ($url -as [uri]).Authority

# Diagnostic output.
"$url`n"
"$cleanURL`n"
```

---

##### Background information:

- A variable used with a  `[ref]` cast that is passed to an `out` or `ref` .NET method parameter *must already exist*.

  - You cannot just *declare* variables in PowerShell, you must *initialize them with a value* in order to *create* them.
  - Variables passed (via `[ref]`) to `out` method parameters by definition will receive a *new value*, so the specific initialization value does *not* matter, and the simplest solution is to *assign `$null`*: without *type-constraining* such a variable (see next point), this is safe to do, irrespective of the data type the variable will later receive.
  - However, you may - but don't have to - *type-constrain* your variable with the target data type, in which case you must assign a type-compatible initial value, e.g. `[datetime] $dt = 0` (`$null` wouldn't work here, because it cannot be converted to `[datetime]`).
    That said, unless you plan to later assign to the same variable *again* - and need the assurance that the value's type won't change - there's little to be gained from using a type constraint.
- Unlike in C#, where `ref` and `out` are *keywords*, in PowerShell [`[ref]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSReference) is a *type*, and must applied as a *cast* to the target variable *directly*.

  - Something like `[ref] [System.Uri] $NewUri`, i.e. a *double* cast, is not only unnecessary, but *doesn't work* (variable `$NewUri` is never filled): it is therefore unfortunate that it is  *quietly accepted*, and this problematic behavior is discussed in [GitHub issue #16146](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16146).
- See also:

  - The official `[ref]` help topic: [about_Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Ref).
  - For more information about type constraints and casts in PowerShell, both of which utilize PowerShell *type literals* (e.g. `[System.Uri]` aka `[uri]`), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66996505/45375).