# How do I replace the first occurrence of a period in a powershell string?

Tags: powershell

I have the following PowerShell:

```
$img="john.smith.jpg"
$img.Replace(".", "")
```

I'm trying to replace the first occurrence of a a period in the string.

At the moment it replaces all periods and returns: "johnsmithjpg"

The output I'm looking for is: "johnsmith.jpg".

I also tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
$img="john.smith.jpg"
[regex]$pattern = "."
$img.replace($img, "", 1)
```

What do I need to do to get it to only replace the first period?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40089631/2864740

Comment: @user2864740 please see above, I've tried this. It doesn't work.

Comment: Try the response with 30 upvotes.

Comment: It is likely that the `.` is not being escaped for the regular expression context (in which case it represents a wildcard character).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Replacing only the first occurrence of a word in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40089631/2864740):

```
$img = "john.smith.jpg"
[regex]$pattern = "\."
$img = $pattern.replace($img, "", 1)
```

Output:

[image]

Note for the pattern, `.` is treated as a wildcard character in regex, so you need to escape it with `\`

Answer (score 1):

Other possibility without RegEx

```
$img="john.smith.jpg"
$img.Remove($img.IndexOf("."),1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that `$img` contains a **filename** including the extension. By blindly replacing the first dot, you might end up with unusable (file)names.
For instance, if you have `$img = 'johnsmith.jpg'` (so the first and only dot there is part of the extension), you may end up with `johnsmithjpg`..

If `$img` is obtained via the `Name` property of a FileInfo object (like Get-Item or Get-ChildItem produces),

change to:

```
$theFileInfoObject = Get-Item -Path 'Path\To\johnsmith.jpg'  # with or without dot in the BaseName
$img = '{0}{1}' -f (($theFileInfoObject.BaseName -split '\.', 2) -join ''), $theFileInfoObject.Extension
# --> 'johnsmith.jpg'
```

Or use .Net:

```
$img = "johnsmith.jpg"  # with or without dot in the BaseName
$img = '{0}{1}' -f (([IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($img) -split '\.', 2) -join ''), [IO.Path]::GetExtension($img)
# --> 'johnsmith.jpg'
```