# Having issues removing string from .txt using Powershell

Tags: string, powershell, csv, text

Purpose: I am currently reading in information and trying to format it as a three column CSV file for future processing (which both the "reading in part" and the "grouping part" are successful). But before the grouping part\building the columns of the CSV, I wish to remove specific words (headers) that throw off the data triplets (this is because as I loop through the data, put 3 items in a row, and then append a newline before repeating until the whole file is read through).

Issue: I am having issues not replacing, but removing a string/element from a .txt file using PowerShell

Code I'm currently using to replace the string(s) with an empty string:

```
$Path = "C:\some.txt"
$Content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($Path)
foreach ($string in (Get-Content "C:\strings_i_wish_to_remove.txt"))
{
$Content = $Content -replace $string, ""
}
$Content | Set-Content -Path $Path
```

And this code snippet works flawlessly with replacing all the words I wish to remove with an empty string; but the issue is that instead of completely removing the existence of the element it's now an empty string which is still processed.

Data before I added the replacement portion:

```
"Data title", "value 1", "value 2"
"Data title", "value 1", "value 2"
"Data title", "value 1", "value 2"
"SECTION HEADER", "Data title", "value 1"
"value 2", "Data title", "value 1"
"value 2", "Data title", "value 1"
"value 2", "Data title", "value 1"
```

Data after I added the replacement portion:

```
"Data title", "value 1", "value 2"
"Data title", "value 1", "value 2"
"Data title", "value 1", "value 2"
"", "Data title", "value 1"
"value 2", "Data title", "value 1"
"value 2", "Data title", "value 1"
"value 2", "Data title", "value 1"
```

Pictured above is the end result of my data after all the processing is complete; and as you can see, if the "SECTION HEADER" was entirely removed it would be aligned properly without any offsetting...

Therefore, is it possible to completely remove the desired word(s) from the file without having any leftover remnants of it still interfering with the subsequent processing steps?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because it is treating "" also as a string and not special char or symbol, you need to include that as well in replace statement, e.g.

`

```
$Path = "d:\some.txt"
$Content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($Path)
$list=Get-Content "d:\strings_i_wish_to_remove.txt"
foreach ($string in $list)
{
$Content = $Content -replace $string, $null
}

//added line below to replace extra text.
$Content= $Content -replace '"",', $null

$Content | Set-Content -Path $Path
```

`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I didn't think of it that way! 

Additionally, would you happen to know how to limit a 'search and replace' to just the first instance of a word? I am curious because it successfully removes all the headers now, but sometimes the header word is also in the data title; so having that blank takes away from some of the data meaning

Comment: As it helped please accept the answer. Also as per the norms we should not raise multiple question in a single question, so always create separate ticket for  new question. To answer your query, follow any method mentioned in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40089631/replacing-only-the-first-occurrence-of-a-word-in-a-string.  Do upvote comment as well if it helps.