# Replace text in a file only a specific number of times

Tags: powershell, batch-file, replace

I have a file with the same text occurring 5 times in total. I now want to only replace the first 2 occurrences with a powershell command within a batch file.

```
Hello -- I want to only
Hello -- replace those.
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

So my file will look like that:

```
Goodbye
Goodbye
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

My code looks like that:

```
powershell -command "$null=new-item -force test.txt -value ((gc -encoding utf8 test.txt) -replace ('^.*$','Goodbye') | out-string)"
```

I tried using the answer to [Replacing only the first occurrence of a word in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40089631/replacing-only-the-first-occurrence-of-a-word-in-a-string):

```
powershell -command "$null=new-item -force test.txt -value ((gc -encoding utf8 test.txt) -replace ('^.*$','Goodbye',2) | out-string)"
```

Which gave me the BadReplaceArgument error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for a direct call to the [`Regex.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-7.0) API, certainly the [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-with-a-script-block) doesn't have an overload for `count`.

```bash
$re = [regex]::new('^.*', [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline)

$re.Replace(@'
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
'@, 'Goodbye', 2)
```

If doing a CLI call the following might work (note, the use of `-Raw` on `Get-Content` is very important here!):

```bash
powershell -Command @'
$re = [regex]::new('^.*', [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline)
$re.Replace((Get-Content -Encoding utf8 test.txt -Raw), 'Goodbye', 2) |
    Set-Content test.txt
'@
```

Comment: I tried using the CLI call but it didn't work. The console closes itself when trying to execute the command.

That's the code I am trying to run:
```powershell -Command @'
$re = [regex]::new('^SceneCaptureStreamingMultiplier *=.*', [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline)
$re.Replace((Get-Content -Encoding utf8 test.txt -Raw), 'SceneCaptureStreamingMultiplier=1.000000', 2) |
 Set-Content test.txt
'@```

Comment: @leiseg, Santiago's syntax only works from _inside_ PowerShell. From `cmd.exe`, use a single-line `"..."` string as the `-Command` argument.

Comment: @mklement0 This works! Thank you once again.